# Dynamically change form submit button depending on value in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

This should be easy, but after browsing several libraries (jquery preferred!) and even plain old javascript, I'm drawing a blank.

In other words, a row with 3 edit boxes, 2 prefilled with type of, say, cheese and pickle, then one unfilled box for a number, and a submit button to the right of that.
Repeat times n rows.

To put it another way:
Imagine a form presented as a series of rows from a search result.
Let's say there are 8 results, that's 8 rows. The user can save their choices into any of 100 "slots".
It's easy if each row can have a name or letter; I just call each submit button a number, 1 to 8, and when say 6 is pressed, it know it's row 6 it wants to save. It uses Malsup's jquery form thing to submit it in an ajaxy way so that the form doesn't have to be refreshed each time.

But that doesn't allow free choice of which "slot" that result is saved in. If I could get the submit button to reflect the number in the cell to the left of it, I'd be away.

But I can't, so I'm not. And I appear to be the only person to do such a nonsense thing.
Any better way?

Comment: When you say the submit button should reflect this, do you mean for instance the name of the submit button, so you can pick it up in code?

Comment: If you know you pressed '6', you can get the value of the third edit in row 6 as well, right? If that edit contains the slot number, you can use that number to save the row. I don't see the problem, but maybe that's because I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your submit button is a button element.

```
$('table').delegate('button', 'click', function(e) {

  var formData = {}

  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function() {
    formData[this.name] = this.value;
  });

  //Add in your code to ajax it off...

  e.preventDefault(); //since buttons/submits behave differently in each browser.

});
```

//Now you have all your formData in an object.  Send it via your Ajax thing.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry it took me so long to mark this as an answer. Personal stuff came up. As it happens, I couldn't get the above to work for me in this instance BUT your bit of code gave me 3 very good hints about what I can do with jQuery and I've used bits in other parts of the page. So, thank you!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad could share some jQuery knowledge around!